# How to create synchronized variables in powershell?

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-scripting, powershell-7.0

If I want to modify a shared variable across two or more `start-job/Start-Threadjob` and I want synchronization of data to make sure there is no inconsistency, how should I go about it?
For example:

```
#synchronized variable
$a = 1
for(i=0;i lt -5; $i++)
    Start-Job {Write-Host $using:a; $local=$using:a; $local++}
```

The above code should output 1,2,3,4,5 without any updation inconsistencies.

Comment: Jobs are hosted in separate processes, you can't share "live variables" between them. Can you tell us more about the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I want to upload multiple files parallely using a REST api. Therefore I want to parallely upload each file and also keep track of which files are uploaded and which are failing so that I can retry later.

Comment: To me it is still unclear, why you need to share a "live variable" between jobs. Could you provide a less abstract sample that shows what you actually want to do using REST API?

Comment: Sounds like you want to take a look at the [BitsTransfer module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) included in Windows